# Marketing cloud SOAP API authentication

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am trying to test the functionality of FuelSDK (https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python) for Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

I created a Developer Account on Salesforce and logged into Marketing Cloud. In their documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/developer-centers/marketing-cloud/ I am following the `Step 1: Install a Package` manual (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/install-packages.htm).

I go to Setup > Apps > Packaging > Package Manager and click `New` there (the options from the manual are not there, but I assume they just renamed some fields). After filling the Name and the Description, however, I don't see the info about `Package ID`, `JWT Signing Secret`, and `Source Account`. Consequently, I can't add API integrations. Consequently I can't get the ClientID and Client Secret (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/api-integration.htm).

Any idea how I could make this work please?

Comment: [salesforce.se] SE has answers to similar question(s)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62916165/calling-marketing-cloud-apis-from-c-sharp-via-fuelsdk

Answer (score 0):

When you login in SFMC, Setup , and click install app, you will window wth name and desc options.

Once you enter it you will get Package ID, JWT Signing Secret.

when you component to package, you will get the client id and secret

hope this helps